# Como converter texto utf-8 para ANSI. Delphi 2006

Tags: delphi, ansi, delphi-2006

Como converter texto `utf-8` para `ANSI`. As palavras que usam "**~**" e "**´**" estão saindo erradas, veja por exemplo o uso da palavra "**PREPARAÇÃO**" que está saindo: "**PREPARA 플O**" ao  gerar arquivo *.CSV* usando *Delphi 2006*.

Comment: Vai depender do tipo do objeto que você está usando para salvar esses arquivo. Posta o trecho de código que facilita a nossa vida.

Comment: Essa é a parte que eu passo os dados para serem gravados..

if Tipo = 'C' then
    Write(ARQTXT, EReplicate(AnsiToUtf8(Texto), ' ', Tamanho));

  Write(ARQTXT, ';');
  Application.ProcessMessages

Comment: Resolvido! Basta fazer assim:
// Antes de iniciar a gravar no arquivo
Write(ARQTXT,#$EF+#$BB+#$BF);

//Depois use utf8encode() ao gravar os dados no arquivo...
Write(ARQTXT,utf8encode(Texto));

E pronto você tem um arquivo no fotmato UTF-8.

Comment: @JoaoBoscodosReisBecker se consegui ajudar com a minha resposta, pode aceitar a resposta clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma. Se necessitar de alguma mais ajuda avise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente utilizar o seguinte código, segundo a resposta dada a esta pergunta no   [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613521/converting-utf8-to-ansi-iso-8859-1-in-delphi) o problema foi resolvido usando a função interna do *Delphi* `UTF8toAnsi` e mais uma função que postei abaixo, utilizando a versão *Delphi 2010*.

```
function TFormMain.convertir_utf8_ansi(const Source: string):string;
var
   Iterator, SourceLength, FChar, NChar: Integer;
begin
   Result := '';
   Iterator := 0;
   SourceLength := Length(Source);
   while Iterator < SourceLength do
   begin
      Inc(Iterator);
      FChar := Ord(Source[Iterator]);
      if FChar >= $80 then
      begin
         Inc(Iterator);
         if Iterator > SourceLength then break;
         FChar := FChar and $3F;
         if (FChar and $20) <> 0 then
         begin
            FChar := FChar and $1F;
            NChar := Ord(Source[Iterator]);
            if (NChar and $C0) <> $80 then break;
            FChar := (FChar shl 6) or (NChar and $3F);
            Inc(Iterator);
            if Iterator > SourceLength then break;
         end;
         NChar := Ord(Source[Iterator]);
         if (NChar and $C0) <> $80 then break;
         Result := Result + WideChar((FChar shl 6) or (NChar and $3F));
      end
      else
         Result := Result + WideChar(FChar);
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var source, result: string;
begin
  source := 'PREPARAÇÃO';
  result := Utf8toAnsi(convertir_utf8_ansi(source));
end;
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/128497)

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis tentei pormenorizar mais a informação, espero ter conseguido melhorar a resposta.

Comment: esse código postado aqui, não é o que está na pergunta no S.O. em ingles como o código que **não funciona**????